# Где посмотреть названия параметров для Ozon Seller API?

Tags: php, api

Я использую Ozon Seller API, передаю новый товар, но есть параметры, у которых я не знаю кодовое название для передачи. Например чтобы передать тип налогообложения, как называется параметр который нужно передать?

Comment: В их доках совсем ничего нет?

Comment: Смотрел, но там из параметров, в основном про атрибуты пишет.

Answer (score 0):

В документации есть следующий запрос https://docs.ozon.ru/api/seller/#operation/CategoryAPI_DictionaryValueBatch
Нужно подставить id озоновской категории товара и id атрибута